# How does one make 6000 iPad photos editable?

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos, photos.app

History - many years of Apple devices - MacBooks, iPhones, iPads.

Result= 8000+ photos viewable on iPad but 6000 of them won't sync with Photo or iMazing.

A workaround is for each photo to try to edit then say yes to "Duplicate and Edit" (and then edit a bit so it will save it) but I can't do this with 6000+ - its impractical.

I need a better fix. I need them ALL of them to be editable and thus seen by iTunes/Photos.

Since I can't see the files with any device but the iPad what can I do?

This must have happened to others too.

The devices/Libraries from which they originally came are no longer in service so going back there is not a solution. I don't want to delete them, just "free them" from association with a device.

Note: I could probably bulk-export to Dropbox or similar, but I'd lose the Metadata on them.

Comment: I seem to recall that a Windows PC will see *some* of the iOS file system (Its been a while since I tried this...) but if you have access to a PC with iTunes it should show up as a drive in Win Explorer and let you drag photos (DCIM folder [?]), in and out. And as the iTunes sync just copies pictures to your profile's pictures folder that might work as well.

Comment: You might want to try the trial version of [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to see if you can extract a few of the troublesome image files to your Mac. If it works, purchase the app. iExplorer is quite a handy tool for more than data recovery outside of the Apple utilities and has come in handy for me for many years. _Disclosure: I'm a satisfied user of iExplorer, and have no financial or other ties to Macroplant LLC._

Comment: Can you bulk-export them to Dropbox, OneDrive or similar?

Comment: Thanks for the iExplorer tip - I'll try it.

Comment: bulk-export to Dropbox or similar - I probably could but I'd lose the Metadata on them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not turn on iCloud photos for a bit, pay for storage if needed and then export and clean them up from there, from back to free storage once you’ve gotten them all wrangled?

With that few photos, you might still be in the free storage tier. I had to bump up to the middle storage when I crossed 40,000 photos in my cloud synced photo library.

This preserves metadata, you can speed it up greatly with a Mac you borrow / own and turn on content caching so you have faster uploads and downloads as you are cleaning things.

Once they are synced to the Mac, your automation and cleanup options are vastly improved, but getting them in iCloud fixes many issues with library initiated photos made via wired connections from the past.